# Group array of objects by 1 key, and split 1 attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, group-by

I have this array of objects

```
test = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'XYZ'
        'value': 10
        'quantity': 100
    }, 
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'XYZ'
        'value': 20
        'quantity': 200
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'ABC'
        'value': 11
        'quantity': 111
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'ABC'
        'value': 22
        'quantity': 222
    }
]
```

And I want to group them by the id, but with the name and the {value, quantity} separated, like this:

```
result = {
    1: [
        'name': 'XYZ'
        'items': [
            {
                'value': 10
                'quantity': 100
            },
            {
                'value': 20
                'quantity': 200
            }
        ]
    ], 
    2: [
        'name': 'ABC'
        'items': [
            {
                'value': 11
                'quantity': 111
            },
            {
                'value': 22
                'quantity': 222
            }
        ]
    ], 
}
```

Any idea how I could do this? Grouping by the id I can do, but then I cannot extract the name.
Thanks

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Are id and name always correlated? i.e. is it impossible to have a situation where an item with id 1 (for instance) has name XYZ and another item has id 1 with name UIO?

Comment: `1` or `2` should be an `object`

Comment: @BenStephens yes they are always correlated, the thing is I need both values

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `reduce()` in this case to group the elements by `id`

```js
const test = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'XYZ',
        'value': 10,
        'quantity': 100,
    }, 
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'XYZ',
        'value': 20,
        'quantity': 200,
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'ABC',
        'value': 11,
        'quantity': 111,
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'ABC',
        'value': 22,
        'quantity': 222,
    }
];

const res = test.reduce((ac, {id, name, ...rest}) => ({...ac, [id]: ac[id] ? [...ac[id], rest] : [rest] }), {});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: name property is missing in output

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "XYZ",
    value: 10,
    quantity: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "XYZ",
    value: 20,
    quantity: 200,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ABC",
    value: 11,
    quantity: 111,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ABC",
    value: 22,
    quantity: 222,
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, name, value, quantity } = curr;
  if (acc[id]) {
    acc[id].items.push({ value, quantity });
  } else {
    acc[id] = {
      name,
      items: [{ value, quantity }],
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` in order to get what you need:

```js
test = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'XYZ',
        value: 10,
        quantity: 100,
    }, 
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'XYZ',
        value: 20,
        quantity: 200,
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ABC',
        value: 11,
        quantity: 111,
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ABC',
        value: 22,
        quantity: 222,
    }
];

res = {};

test.forEach(el => {
    let key = el.id;
    if (!res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        res[key] = {
            name: el.name,
            items: []
        };
    }
    res[key].items.push({value: el.value, quantity: el.quantity});
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `id` and `name` and get the rest of the object ([Rest in Object Destructuring `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)) as `item`.

Then assign a new object if not exists for the property `id` and push `item` to the `items` array of the group.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'XYZ', value: 10, quantity: 100 }, { id: 1, name: 'XYZ', value: 20, quantity: 200 }, { id: 2, name: 'ABC', value: 11, quantity: 111 }, { id: 2, name: 'ABC', value: 22, quantity: 222 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { id, name, ...item }) => {
        r[id] ??= { name, items: [] };
        r[id].items.push(item);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```